# Remove Woocomerce Tax information string/text from Total row and Add it to the Subtotal row

Tags: customization, hook-woocommerce, tax

Here I am working on a project where I need to show the Including Taxs just after the Subtotal Price, but currently it is showing after the Total price as a default.

Can anybody please tell me how to do so with/without using a woocomerce hook or template override so that my changes wouldn't get effected while updating.

[image: screenshot]

https://ibb.co/ZXh7Kx6

Thanks in advance.